# JaCoCo in Sonar does not include all source files

Tags: ant, sonarqube, jacoco

I use JaCoCo for IT coverage in Sonar in Java language. Some IT code coverage is reported, and the reported results appear to be sound. However, I noticed that not all source code was included in the IT coverage analysis. Looking at the "Components" view, many Java packages show rules %, cobertura unit test coverage %, but nothing for IT coverage. I have not included or excluded any files, I would therefore expect IT coverage to show 0% if no code from this package was covered? I know there should be some % on a set of files, but Sonar does not display anything for it (again, rules % and cobertura % are shows).

I will try to explicitly include some class files, but I am still puzzled regarding why all sources are not included for JaCoCo analysis. The files are imported to Sonar because rules violations work fine on them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that if you do not see any results on some specific files/packages, this probably means that no IT covers those parts of your source code.

Comment: Hmm but I would then expect to get 0% on them, because displaying nothing would indicate that the source code is excluded from analysis. Secondly, I know some of the sources are covered. Sonar displays nothing on a whole Java project, and definitely some of them are covered (they are Web modules, i.e. display pages, etc. related)